# How to make non-sequential ranges unique?

Tags: t-sql, gaps-and-islands, scd

I am strugling with some T-SQL code to get column [Num] (in below example table). Basically, I am trying to create an index on when a new sequence of [Type] is starting.

**Q: How to create the [num] field below?**

[Num] is the order of sequential ranges of field [Type]. You see that from 2022-01-01 to 2022-01-03 [Type] = 'Working'. Then on 2022-01-07, a new range of sequential rows with the same type starts (only one day though) and therefore it is 2. Basically, if there is no sequential days of the same type and another day pops up with a different type, the range stops. When a new day starts with that same type (> 1 days later), a new range starts. You can assume there cannot be different types on one day in my case.

What makes it tricky for me is that I cannot partition it on Type as it is recurring in a new sequence later on using a regular row_number.

Some extra explanation why I need this: I am creating a SCD dimension with a valid from and valid to date by taking the min and max grouped by [Type]. But since [Type] is recurring this does not work. I need a way to make each nonsequential series of [Type] unique.
I am of course open to other suggestions if my solution is sub optimal.

Table_1

| Date | Type | Num |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | Working | 1 |
| 2022-01-02 | Working | 1 |
| 2022-01-03 | Working | 1 |
| 2022-01-04 | Resting | 1 |
| 2022-01-05 | Resting | 1 |
| 2022-01-06 | Resting | 1 |
| 2022-01-07 | Working | 2 |
| 2022-01-08 | Resting | 2 |
| 2022-01-09 | Resting | 2 |
| 2022-01-10 | Resting | 2 |
| 2022-01-11 | Resting | 2 |
| 2022-01-12 | Resting | 2 |
| 2022-01-12 | Traveling | 1 |
| 2022-01-13 | Working | 3 |
| 2022-01-14 | Traveling | 2 |
| 2022-01-15 | Working | 4 |
| 2022-01-16 | Working | 4 |

Thank you so much!

**Update**:

I omit the information that is in my belief not necessary.

The end goal of this question is to create a table as below (table_2). If I have field [num] in table_1 I will be able to create table_2 myself but I am open to suggestions as well of course.

Table_2

| Date | Type | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | Working | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-03 |
| 2022-01-04 | Resting | 2022-01-04 | 2022-01-06 |
| 2022-01-07 | Working | 2022-01-07 | 2022-01-07 |
| 2022-01-08 | Resting | 2022-01-08 | 2022-01-12 |
| 2022-01-12 | Traveling | 2022-01-12 | 2022-01-12 |
| 2022-01-13 | Working | 2022-01-13 | 2022-01-13 |
| 2022-01-14 | Traveling | 2022-01-14 | 2022-01-14 |
| 2022-01-15 | Working | 2022-01-15 | 2022-01-16 |

Comment: YOu don't explain what the logic to get those values are, so we don't know how you need to achieve it. At a *guess* this is a gaps and island problem

Comment: Please see my update. I belief the question is simply: how can I query  [num]?

But I have also added more on the 'why', although I belief this does not impact the change the fundamental question of 'how I can query [Num]?'

Comment: It doesn't answer my question though. Why are the first 6 rows `1`, then the next 6 `2`, but then the one after `1` again?

Comment: It is the order of sequential ranges of field [Type]. You see that from 2022-01-01 to 2022-01-03 [Type] = 'Working'. Then on 2022-01-07, a new range of sequential rows with the same type starts (only one day though) and therefore it is 2.

Basically, if there is no sequential days of the same type and another day pops up with a different type, the range stops.  When a new day starts with that same type (> 1 days later), a new range starts. 

You can assume there cannot be different types on one day in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic gaps and island problem. Find your islands, and then `DENSE_RANK` them:

```sql
WITH Grps AS(
SELECT V.Date,
       V.Type,
       V.Num,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY V.Date) - 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY V.[Type] ORDER BY V.[Date]) AS Grp
FROM (VALUES(CONVERT(date,'2022-01-01'),'Working',1),
            (CONVERT(date,'2022-01-02'),'Working',1),
            (CONVERT(date,'2022-01-03'),'Working',1),
            (CONVERT(date,'2022-01-04'),'Resting',1),
            (CONVERT(date,'2022-01-05'),'Resting',1),
            (CONVERT(date,'2022-01-06'),'Resting',1),
            (CONVERT(date,'2022-01-07'),'Working',2),
            (CONVERT(date,'2022-01-08'),'Resting',2),
            (CONVERT(date,'2022-01-09'),'Resting',2),
            (CONVERT(date,'2022-01-10'),'Resting',2),
            (CONVERT(date,'2022-01-11'),'Resting',2),
            (CONVERT(date,'2022-01-12'),'Resting',2),
            (CONVERT(date,'2022-01-12'),'Traveling',1),
            (CONVERT(date,'2022-01-13'),'Working',3),
            (CONVERT(date,'2022-01-14'),'Traveling',2),
            (CONVERT(date,'2022-01-15'),'Working',4),
            (CONVERT(date,'2022-01-16'),'Working',4))V([Date], [Type], Num))
SELECT G.Date,
       G.Type,
       G.Num AS YourNum,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY G.Type ORDER BY Grp) AS CalcedNum
FROM Grps G
ORDER BY G.Date;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Larnu! That step where you deduct those two row numbers is a trick I would never have found myself now! 
Also, very much thank you for the exact example you provided. This is great!

Also my apologies for my OP where I wasn't complete in my communication. I really thought my message was enough to grasp the problem, but now I see it is not indeed. Will be more precise a next time! :)

I will add my comment explaining this to the OP  as well.